# How to stop processes to umount mountpoint for fsck

Tags: process, fsck, unmounting

I am trying to do fsck on the NAS via ssh on /volume1. The volume has to be unmounted, and all processes with reference to /volume1 need to be stopped accordingly. Therefore, logged in as root, all processes have been stopped, with the exception of:

```
root@StoreMachine:~# lsof /volume1
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
sh       1668 admin  cwd    DIR  253,0     4096 289341888 /volume1/homes/admin
sudo    11561  root  cwd    DIR  253,0     4096 289341888 /volume1/homes/admin
lsof    16852  root  txt    REG  253,0   129652 265781642 /volume1/@optware/sbin/lsof
lsof    16852  root  mem    REG  253,0 10747920 265782212 /volume1/@optware/lib/locale/locale-archive
lsof    16852  root  mem    REG  253,0  1218228 265781308 /volume1/@optware/lib/libc-2.25.so
lsof    16852  root  mem    REG  253,0   134332 265781320 /volume1/@optware/lib/ld-2.25.so
lsof    16853  root  txt    REG  253,0   129652 265781642 /volume1/@optware/sbin/lsof
lsof    16853  root  mem    REG  253,0 10747920 265782212 /volume1/@optware/lib/locale/locale-archive
lsof    16853  root  mem    REG  253,0  1218228 265781308 /volume1/@optware/lib/libc-2.25.so
lsof    16853  root  mem    REG  253,0   134332 265781320 /volume1/@optware/lib/ld-2.25.so
```

I am not able to stop above processes when I'm logged in as root via ssh on the NAS. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot stop the processes or unmount all the `/volume1/` mounts. If you could, your system would stop working. You might try `sudo touch /volume1/forcefsck` followed by a reboot. Check: `grep "forcefsck" /etc/rc?.d/* /etc/init.d/* /etc/init/* /etc/rc.local`